# Umbraco. Get node's url in console application

Tags: c#, console, umbraco

I work with Umbraco from Console application.
When I try get `NiceUrl` for some node  it is impossible  because  `UmbracoContext.Current` is null.

I can get node path with ids like this: "-1,1067,1080", but don't know how convert it in url format.

How Can I get `NiceUrl` for Node in console application?

I did next:
 In my console application I get node by Id, simple like this:

```
Node someNode = new Node(nodeId);
```

When I try get NiceUrl:

```
string url = someNode.NiceUrl;
```

get ArgumentNullException.

I checked why it: found next answer `NiceUrl` uses UmbracoContext so it is not possible because it's null.

Also I can't use this: `UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetById(someidhere).Url`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have tried?

Comment: @TimWagaman I edited the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't use: `UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache` because this is accessing the same context.

It looks like you are using v6+, so instead you will need to use the API services that Umbraco provide, specifically the ContentService.

There is a thread here that looks into the same thing you are asking: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/37981-Using-v6-API-ContentService-in-external-application

And an example of a solution here: https://github.com/sitereactor/umbraco-console-example

Comment: not sure how this is given as an answer. both links dont help you. neither resolves a node to a url. perhaps the upvote was for your first paragraph.

Comment: @Christo Hah, don't jump to conclusions :) The question isn't just about resolving a node to a URL but doing so from within a console application. Since you don't have access to the published content cache outside of an Umbraco application context, you need to use the API services. The links refer to strategies for creating Umbraco-aware console apps. From there, retrieving a URL is simple.

Answer (score 3):

Without the UmbracoContext I don't think it's possible in V6 to get the URL of an IContent node.

I looked through the Umbraco source code and decided to recreate the way it's done there.  I came up with this, which worked for my needs.

https://gist.github.com/petergledhill/ca2a3a0ea81b06abcb08

```
public static class ContentExtensions
{                
    public static string RelativeUrl(this IContent content)
    {
        var pathParts = new List<string>();
        var n = content;

        while (n != null)
        {
            pathParts.Add(n.UrlName());
            n = n.Parent();                
        }
        pathParts.RemoveAt(pathParts.Count() - 1); //remove root node
        pathParts.Reverse();
        var path = "/" + string.Join("/", pathParts);
        return path;
    }    

    public static string UrlName(this IContent content)
    {
        return new DefaultUrlSegmentProvider().GetUrlSegment(content).ToLower();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Nice. I hadn't come across this before. I'll have a dig around with this.